# Oracle Virtual Columns in Google Big Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a Warehouse in Oracle with some tables that have virtual columns.
If we want to migrate this warehouse to Google Big Query, what options do we have for Oracle virtual column.

Regards,
Sreekanth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate virtual columns with a logical view. For example, suppose that table `project.dataset.transactions` has columns `transaction_date` and `transaction_id`, but you would like to have virtual columns for `transaction_year` (as an INT64) and `transaction_week` (as an INT64 as well). You can create a logical view such as:

```
CREATE VIEW `project.dataset.transactions_view` AS
SELECT
  transaction_date,
  transaction_id,
  EXTRACT(ISOYEAR FROM transaction_date) AS transaction_year,
  EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM transaction_date) AS transaction_week
FROM `project.dataset.transactions`;
```